# Server can't reach more than 800mbps

Tags: streaming, rate-limiting

I'm using wowza for streaming video and I've a server on linode (8gbps upload).

I had streaming and when the server reaches 800 mbps, approximately, streaming begins to suffer lag and the upload speed lows.

More and more users but the upload speed remains or low instead of rise.

Here an graphic example :

[image]

Otherwise, the stream had a bitrate of 2Mbps, namely, when I had 400 users , my server only use 700mbps maximum :S.

The server has : 64 GB ram 20 Cores (E5) 1536 GB SSD 40 Gbps IN 8000 Mbps OUT. 
I'm streaming from OBS to my server. the server is hosted in Frankfurt and 99% viewers are spanish

Sorry for my english, regards.

Comment: Have you gathered performance stats on the server itself?  What is its CPU usage, what is the I/O usage.  What is your disk queue lengths, are you using all the RAM.  etc.  Anyway, **gather data, look for bottlenecks, remove them.**

Comment: Can you reach more than 800mbps for users from Germany? There could be limit on transit data transfers (transfer to different states). Check another monitoring values if there is not any bottleneck.